# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, get, mongoose

Добрый день.
Такую ошибку выдает mongoose при попытке сохранить запись.
Код следующий:
Модель Car.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Машины
var Car = new mongoose.Schema({
        id: Number,
        source: String,

})

var CarModel = mongoose.model('Car', Car);
module.exports =  CarModel
```

Сохранение:

```
exports.saveData = function(expr){
data = expr.data;
switch(expr.type){
    case "cars":
        console.log(expr);
        console.log('Data to save:' + data);
        return new Car(data).save()
        break
    default:
        return { error: "no type given" }
    }

}
```

Ну и вызов сохранения:

```
app.get('/data', function(req, res){
    if(req.query.data == '') res.send('Bad data');
    if(req.query.type == '') res.send('Bad type');
    var result = api.saveData(req.query);
    if(result.error) res.send(result.error);
    else res.send("OK");
});
```

Запрос соответственно следующий(делается из строки браузера):

```
http://localhost:8080/data?type=cars&data='[{"id":"1111111111","source":"out"}]'
```

Соответственно пробовал разные вариации data:

```
data=[{"id":"1111111111","source":"out"}]
data={"id":"1111111111","source":"out"}
data={id:"1111111111",source:"out"}
data=[{id:"1111111111",source:"out"}]
data=id:"1111111111",source:"out"
```

Всегда одна и та же ошибка.
Понимаю, что ошибка в передаче поля data, но вот какая, мне не ясно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://localhost:8080/data?type=cars&data={"id":"1111111111","source":"out"}
```

все параметры в запросе приходят в виде строки, так что перед созданием документа нужно преобразовать ее в объект (JSON.parse(data))

```
return new Car(JSON.parse(data)).save()
```

---

в вашем случае происходило следующее:

return new Car(      **'**      [{"id":"1111111111","source":"out"}]      **'**      ).save()